# How can I use ClipRRect and ListTile inside Row?

Tags: flutter

I want to use ClipRRect and ListTile inside Row but it gives an error. Please help me to resolve this error.

**Code**

```
body: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(height: 20),
      Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
        child: Row(
    
          children: [
            Container(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                child: Image(image: AssetImage('mobile1.jpg'), ),
    
              ), ),
            ListTile(
    
              title: Text("I Phone 6"),
              subtitle: Text("data"),
            )
          ])),
    ]
), );
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want to mention the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the exact solving you need to give the stacktrace. Thought it was a layout overflow issue and I solved as follows:

```
Column(children: [
    SizedBox(height: 20),
    Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
        child: Row(
          children: [
          Container(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('mobile1.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text("I Phone 6"),
              subtitle: Text("data"),
            ),
          )
        ])),
  ])
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution:

This is an overflow problem.

It can be solved like this, (has some extras )

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(height: 20),
      Card(
        // this elevation is purely for shape and is not related to
        // solving the problem.
        elevation: 10,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        // this padding widget is purely for shape and is not related to
        // solving the problem.
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                // here I added some height and width so the image
                // follows them and be smaller or larger than the card.
                width: 130,
                height: 130,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  // your image, I used a network one.
                  //
                  // child: Image(
                  //   image: AssetImage('mobile1.jpg'),
                  // ),
                  child: Image.network(
                    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/699122/pexels-photo-699122.jpeg",
                    // this line makes the image cover the area, this will
                    // allow the roundness to appear.
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // this expanded widget makes the list tile take the empty
              // space after the image and not any less or more.
              Expanded(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text("I Phone 6"),
                  subtitle: Text("data"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

#### Result:

[image: result]